# Java Form file - MenuItem Separator

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, menuitem

I inherited some code that used NetBeans and created .form files as well as .java files.  However, we're using Eclipse.  I've successfully updated the .java files (to add a Help Menu) but am not sure what the code is for the form file.  I want to keep it up to date even though I'm not using NetBeans.
My question is: **What is the form code to add a separator for a JMenu MenuItem?**

In java, I have:

```
menu.addSeparator();
```

My form file looks like:

```
            <MenuItem class="javax.swing.JMenuItem" name="helpMenu">
          <Properties>
            <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" value="Help"/>
          </Properties>
          <Events>
            <EventHandler event="actionPerformed" listener="java.awt.event.ActionListener" parameters="java.awt.event.ActionEvent" handler="helpMenuActionPerformed"/>
          </Events>
        </MenuItem>
```

Comment: Note `.form` file is intended to use with NetBeans' GUI Builder. It's actually auto-generated using this tool. Not sure if you can make it "work" in Eclipse.

Comment: I would suggest you use Netbeans to edit the component. I'm also having to work with NetBeans generated dialog, panel and such and keep using Netbeans to modify them to avoid the burden.

Comment: You could try [this plugin, windowbuilder for eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)

Comment: If you use NetBeans, and put in a separator, what is the generated output in the form file please?